# How ROW_NUMBER() working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, row-number

As we known that Row_number() returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition. However, how does it work in the basement? For example, using the bookmark or index?

Best Regards

Comment: Looks like Google Translate has failed you or my English has failed me. I do not understand the last sentence.

Comment: If there is no index on the table it can't use an index. Bookmarks only get used when you are using an index to look up the clustered index. Why does it matter how it works behind he scenes?

Comment: I mean that how does it work to return the number of row. Does it calculate rows from 1 to let's say 100? Or some other method like assigning number for the address of memory. @Alex

Comment: @PleasecallmeaJ - look at the actual query execution plan. You will see that effectively it runs a sort followed by GROUP BY on the result set. I have no idea how low level operations (how the values are stored in memory etc.) are performed. You have to ask Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #test_rownumber
(
 name varchar(50)
,score float
,date_stamp varchar(20)
)

insert into #test_rownumber values('A',40,'2015-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('A',50,'2015-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('A',60,'2015-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('A',70,'2017-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('B',60,'2015-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('B',70,'2015-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('B',90,'2016-06-02')
insert into #test_rownumber values('B',100,'2017-06-02')


--you will see the row_number partion by name ,order by sore desc 
SELECT 
 name 
,score
,date_stamp 
,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by name order by score desc) as row_num
from #test_rownumber

--if you want to know the name and its' best score ,your may use that
select 
 name 
,score
,date_stamp 
from(
SELECT 
 name 
,score
,date_stamp 
,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by name order by score desc) as row_num
from #test_rownumber
) a 
where row_num=1
```